# pip and python path don't match

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, raspberry-pi

When I run my script using python... it says "module not found". But then I do "pip install [module] and it says it:

Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Requirement already satisfied: python-osc in /home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (1.7.4)

```
which pip:
/home/pi/.local/bin/pip

which python:
/usr/bin/python3
```

or

```
which pip3:
/home/pi/.local/bin/pip3
which python3:
/usr/bin/python3
```

I think it may be because the paths don't match? How can I correct this issue? Thank you.

Comment: Python is part of your distribution and is installed as /usr/bin/python[3]. However in the user context you don't have permissions to install modules in the system location, which is a good thing. so the modules are installed in ~/.local/, if you run echo $PATH, you will see that ~/.local is defined before the system location, thus masking system pip if it exists at all.

Comment: is your script for python or python3?

Comment: @mestia thank you for your reply, but how do I sold this? It's for python3

Comment: I guess, that pip is for python2.7 and pip3 is for python 3.x on your system. If you run your script with python3 <path_to_script> and it says module is not found, try to install it with pip3: pip3 install --user <modulename>

Comment: @mestia that's how I tried to install the package and got the error message of already being installed but in the wrong location

Comment: I see, could you please check the permissions of l ~/.local/lib/python3.7/ ?

Comment: @mestia how do I do that? when I run in the terminal "$ ~/.local/lib/python3.7/" I get: -bash: /home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/: Is a directory

Comment: sorry, there was a typo, it should have been ls -l ~/.local/lib/python3.7/

Comment: @mestia I get this: pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ls -l ~/.local/lib/python3.7/ 
total 12
drwx------ 180 pi pi 12288 Feb  4 19:46 site-packages

Comment: I misinterpreted the message, it is actually saying that you do have the module installed - Requirement already satisfied: python-osc in /home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (1.7.4)